# Custom smiley in uitextfield

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, chat, xcode4.5, emoji

I have used the following code for showing the smiley in uitextfield.

```
stringWithSmiley = [stringWithSmiley stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":)"
                                    withString:@"\ue415"
                                    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                    range:range];
```

I searched and found that every smileys/emoji icons has its own id,based on that we can show it on the text field.

**My doubt is:**
Is that possible to create custom smileys ?If yes ,then how we can show it in the textfield?

If any body has idea then please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {   

NSRange range = {NSNotFound, 0};
NSString *s = @"This is a smiley :)";

range.location = 0;
range.length = [s length];
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":)"
                                    withString:@"\ue415"
                                    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                    range:range];

  }
```

Comment: This only I have tried and got the result.My question is "How to create new smileys with ids like '\ue415'"?Is that possible?

Comment: @ani...if you want to add your own custom smileys,then you must add image of that smiley along with text using `rightView` property of `UITextfield` .That would be better approach..

Comment: I have tried and the symbol is coming in the right side of the text field.I have to set the image anywhere in the text field .(as like smileys working).Is that possible?

Comment: Just wait... i will provide you working code soon... am also trying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25592/discussion-between-vineet-singh-rawat-and-ani)

Comment: I didn't get solve the issue.I have to add my own smileys(custom) as the existing smileys/emoji icons.Is that possible?

Comment: ohh... let me try.. i'll provide you solution soon :)